# Llamar al logout de Laravel desde el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, login, controller

Estoy intentando bloquear una vista en mi pagina dependiendo de si cumple una condición o no.

Por ejemplo, si mi usuario tiene una cierta cantidad de Strikes acumulados entonces que automaticamente lo desloguee.

```
if ($strikes >=3) {
    return redirect(/logout);
}
```

Pero esto me arroja un error. Como puedo hacer para desloguear a mi usuario si no cumple los requisitos.

Comment: La ruta va como string entre comillas

Comment: Aunque lo que te dice @BetaM seguramente es la solución a tu problema, deberías incluir el mensaje de error en tus preguntas. En la mayoría de ocasiones los mensajes de error son autoexplicativos y en otros, es interesante entender el sentido que tienen para que lo reconozcas rápidamente la próxima vez que recibas el mismo mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer el logout de laravel para redireccionarlo a otro sitio si lo necesitas

```
Auth::logout();
request()->session()->invalidate();
request()->session()->regenerateToken();
return redirect('/');
```